# Pasting into google sheets creates a static time stamp in one cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my test sheet that I am using to try and get this to work: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-KjA7AdLxh6xTLyx3FTP_XuXZlm6vZ0IlrLMO2TTLOE/edit#gid=1008104959

I currently have a working script that will auto update a time stamp in D1 when info in cell B3 is edited. What I would like it to do is the same thing but also function when I paste info(a large data set) that would go onto B3 and down.

this is the script I currently have working, and I just need it to work when info is pasted in B3, not just when it is manually edited:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user edits a cell in the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onOpen() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  if (e.range.getB3Notation() !== 'B3') {
    return;
  }
  var message = 'Hello world! Cell B3 was changed ';
  message += 'from "' + e.oldValue + '" ';
  message += 'to "' + e.value + '".';

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setValue(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 3 && !e.value) {
    sh.getRange("D1").setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

This only capture paste where range starts in B3 and proceeds below

Comment: Ummm, I'm pretty new to working with scrips, but when I tried to use that, it didn't do anything... also, I don't see anything in here that directs that the date stamp to be put into a specific cell. Again I'm pretty new to this so if I'm missing something obvious please let me know.

Comment: I was under the impress that you wished to have the timestamp insert into `sh.getRange("B3:B" + vs.length).  You you rather have the timestamps posted in D1?

Comment: I'm trying to get it so that when I paste a chunk of data into the B3:B range it will update the time stamp in cell D1. Or more specifically, I want it to update the time stamp in D1 whenever the B3 is edited especially when the info is pasted in B3. I have a tool that I take a data set copied from another program and I paste it into the range, and I wanted to have it make a time stamp when I paste that info, and the next time I paste it, then that time stamp updates. Sorry if I didn't make that clear in my initial post.

Comment: @BlaineCarda that's what the bottom one does

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but when I try putting that in the app scrip, it doesn't seem to cause the D1 time stamp to update when I make changes to the B3:B range.

Comment: I just modified it again and I tested it but you will need to change the sheet name

Comment: One last question, can you change it so it isn't limited to a specific sheet, but can work on   any tab in the spreadsheet?

Comment: You Rock!, thanks Copper